# Narrow type based on property union type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to narrow a type to a specific variant of a type. But I'm having troubles defining the correct type.
Right now I have a type `Item` which can have a different type for it's details.

```js
type Item = {
  name: string;
  details: FooDetails | BarDetails;
}

type FooDetails = {
  foo: string;
}

type BarDetails = {
  bar: string;
}
```

I'm creating a React component where I only want to get the `Item` passed in if it's an `Item` with `FooDetails`. How do I correctly come about this?

---

If I just use the type `Item`, and use an `if` in my component to look at the details, TypeScript correctly narrows the type like so:

```js
type Props = {
  item: Item;
}

const FooComponent = ({ item }: Props) => {
  if (!'foo' in item.details) throw new Error('incorrect item'); // How do I avoid this if by having a more specific type in my props?
  
  item.details.foo // this is ok
}
```

I have tried stuff like:

```js
type ItemWithDetails<TDetail> = Item extends infer I ? Extract<I, 'details'> extends TDetail ? I : never : never;

type Props = {
  item: ItemWithDetails<FooDetails>;
}
```

However that seems to always evaluate to `never`.

Comment: Why dont to use just `FooDetails` instead of `Item` in props?

Comment: Keep in mind, TS has structural type system, so any result of your helper type util will be equal to `FooDetails`

Comment: I wanna use `Item` because I need to access both properties from `Item` and `FooDetails` in the component. And I will have a component specific for an `Item` with `FooDetails` and one for `BarDetails`. That was at least my initial thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React from 'react'
type Item = {
  name: string;
}

type FooDetails = {
  foo: string;
}

type BarDetails = {
  bar: string;
}

type FooItem = {
  details: FooDetails
} & Item

type BarItem = {
  details: BarDetails
} & Item

type Props = {
  item: FooItem | BarItem;
}

/**
 * First of all, you should not throw Errors inside your React FooComponent
 * You should instead handle errors in other way - through state for example
 */
const FooComponent0 = ({ item }: Props) => {
  if (!('foo' in item.details)) throw new Error('incorrect item'); // How do I avoid this if by having a more specific type in my props?

  item.details.foo // this is ok
}

/**
 * I prefer next way
 */

const isFoo = (arg: any): arg is FooItem => Boolean(arg.details.foo)
const isBar = (arg: any): arg is BarItem => Boolean(arg.details.bar)

const FooComponent = ({ item }: { item: FooItem }) => <div>{item.details.foo}</div>
const BarComponent = ({ item }: { item: BarItem }) => <div>{item.details.bar}</div>


/**
 * IF you want to make two components for unions
 * You better to do smth like this
 */
const StrategyComponent = (props: Props) => {
  if (isFoo(props.item)) {
    return <FooComponent item={props.item} />
  }
  if (isBar(props.item)) {
    return <BarComponent item={props.item} />
  }
  return null
}
```